# Expected weight of n non-identical balls with given probability distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have n balls with weights chosen from a gives set `{w1, w2, ..., wc}` with probabilities `{Pr1, Pr2, ..., Prc}` respectively. I am looking for a closed-form formula for the expected weight of total balls. As an example, I think for n=3 and c=2 the result should be like this:

```
'Expected Weight = 3*w1*(Pr1)^3+(2*w1+w2)*(Pr1)^2*Pr2+(w1+2*w2)*Pr1*(Pr2)^2+3*w2*(Pr2)^3'
```

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: You have to regard the number of ways to choose 2 balls with weight $w_1$ and one ball with weight $w_2$, for instance. There are three ways in this case: $w_1w_1w_2,w_1w_2w_1,w_2w_1w_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you only care about the weights expectation, you can use the additivity of the expectation. The expected weight of 1 ball is $w_1Pr_1 + w_2Pr_2+...+w_cPr_c$ therefore the expected weight of $n$ balls is that same number times $n$